# TabControl selected index event in windows form application in visual studio

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a windows form application. I made code that buttons should be created at run time on the page selected. The problem is that when I run the program, it sounds like the first page is already selected (but it is empty), so when I click the tab from page1, nothing shows up. When I select page2, the buttons from page2 show up and the same is with the other pages. The funny part is that if I select page1 after I selected already another page, the buttons from page1 show up. The first time I can't even select the first page.

This is my code:

```
private void FruitTab_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FruitTab.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            int x = 0;
            var fruits = (from f in db.Items
                          where f.categoryID == 1
                          select f).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < fruits.Count(); i++, y++)
            {

                var productName = fruits[i];
                Button button = new Button();

                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        x = 0;

                    else if (i != 0)
                    {
                        y = 0;
                        x = x + 150;
                    }
                }


                int xPoint = x;
                int yPoint = 60 * y + 25;

                button.Location = new Point(xPoint, yPoint);
                button.Size = new Size(150, 55);
                button.Tag = i + 1;
                button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickEvent);
                button.Name = button.Tag.ToString();
                button.Text = productName.name;

                button.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;

                // if (productName.Category.categoryname == "fruit")
                fruitTabPage.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
        else if(FruitTab.SelectedIndex==1)
        {
            int x = 0;
            var vegetables = (from f in db.Items
                          where f.categoryID == 2
                          select f).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < vegetables.Count(); i++, y++)
            {

                var productName = vegetables[i];

                Button button = new Button();

                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        x = 0;

                    else if (i != 0)
                    {
                        y = 0;
                        x = x + 150;
                    }
                }


                int xPoint = x;
                int yPoint = 60 * y + 25;

                button.Location = new Point(xPoint, yPoint);
                button.Size = new Size(150, 55);
                button.Tag = i + 1;
                button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickEvent);
                button.Name = button.Tag.ToString();
                button.Text = productName.name;
                button.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
                vegetableTabPage.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
            else if (FruitTab.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                int x = 0;
                var misc = (from f in db.Items
                              where f.categoryID == 3
                              select f).ToArray();

                for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < misc.Count(); i++, y++)
                {

                    var productName = misc[i];

                    Button button = new Button();

                    if (i % 5 == 0)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                            x = 0;

                        else if (i != 0)
                        {
                            y = 0;
                            x = x + 150;
                        }
                    }


                    int xPoint = x;
                    int yPoint = 60 * y + 25;

                    button.Location = new Point(xPoint, yPoint);
                    button.Size = new Size(150, 55);
                    button.Tag = i + 1;
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickEvent);
                    button.Name = button.Tag.ToString();
                    button.Text = productName.name;

                    button.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;

                    // if (productName.Category.categoryname == "fruit")
                    MiscTabPage.Controls.Add(button);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You'll have to throw this away, using the SelectedIndexChanged event to add buttons is quite wrong.  It doesn't just go wrong because you don't get the event for the 1st page, you keep adding buttons every single time you select another tab.  They are on top of each other so the bug isn't that easy to see.

Comment: so which event handler should i use?

Comment: Hard to guess, but surely it belongs in the constructor.